# How Do I Set An Icon For JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I want to set an icon for a jlabel, can somebody give me example syntax

I have tried this :

```
JLabel icon = new JLabel();
ImageIcon chromo = createImageIcon("res/icon.png");
panel.add(icon);
icon.setIcon(chromo);
```

After I tried this the label didn't show up on the panel at all.

Comment: Where in the project is this image located? Have you checked to see that the image isn't null? What does the `createImageIcon` method look like?

Comment: It is located in a package called res with the name icon.png so res/icon.png

Comment: Please show the `createImageIcon` method\

Comment: ImageIcon chromo = createImageIcon("res/icon.png");

Comment: What does that mean _"Its in the syntax"_. The code you've shown is **not** the `createImageIcon` method. It's a **call** to the `createImageIcon` method. We need to see that actual method. That may be where the problem lies. Also check if `chromo` is null

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243724/java-adding-imageicon-to-jlabel

Comment: Sorry if I caused you any trouble but my question was Answered,

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
JLabel icon = new JLabel();
ImageIcon chromo = createImageIcon("res/icon.png");
icon.setIcon(chromo);
panel.add(icon);
```

And don't forget to check your layout, if it is absolute then you need to add bounds to it.

```
icon.setBounds(startX, startY, width, height);
```

Comment: _if its Absolute you need to add bounds_ Nah, if it is absolute, you need to switch to a `LayoutManager`